# Unable to remove space at the bottom of page

Tags: css

I'm experiencing a strange issue where there's 48px of non-margin/padding in between my footer and bottom of page (I've also noticed that if I delete the footer from the DOM, the space is still there below the next element).

[image]

I only noticed it when I applied a background colour to the `body` (yellow in picture). I'm also using a normalize stylesheet and have tried forcing a `margin-bottom` on the footer to no avail.

Basic structure:

```
<footer>
  <section>
  </section>
  <div>
  </div>
  <div>
  </div>
  <div>
  </div>
  <div>
  </div>
  <div>
  </div>
  <div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    outline: none;
}

html {
    font-size: 16px;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fefde1;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #656565;
    position: relative;
}

footer {
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    font-size: 1rem;
}
```

Comment: please share a live snippet code.

Comment: set 100% height of section and section should be outside of footer tag

Comment: Your example code by itself doesn't cause the behaviour you describe. So can you post some code that actually demonstrates the problem?

Comment: The problem is that I don't know what the problematic code is, so if I did, it'd be easier to fix. I'd have to post the entire site and I can't publically.

Comment: add this to css and what you see ? `* { border: 1px solid red;}`

Comment: @DanielH This: http://i.imgur.com/T7R4gnq.jpg. The body extends to the bottom, but the footer doesn't.

Comment: @MarioParra ok you can use your browser and inspect that element block, check the style and you can fix it easily...

Comment: @DanielH Yes, I know how DevTools works, but when I highlight it, it's the `HTML` element, which doesn't have any styling.

Comment: @MarioParra  try to play with html see what happened you can use `margin: -30px !important;` or `padding: -30px !important;` see if anything changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it helps anyone else, the issue was a tracking pixel script that, despite having a `height` of `0`, was adding space to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

I just cant think in 3 things:

1: the body have a margin or a padding that you doesn't noticed.

2: the body have something inside with a margin or border.

3: add a "margin-bottom: -48px;" in the footer. (this is quick and dirt)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should add some reset styles. Check your navigator inspector and select those properties, you would see some "inherit styles" by default.

Try to add this to your body styles:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box
```

}

Comment: I mentioned that I've already applied a normalize stylesheet, which includes: margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;